# How to calculate boost PFC iL, Vout by duty?

Tags: power-factor-correction

When steady state ∆iL - ∆iL‘ = 0 and Vout Vin/(1-D)

∆iL=(Vin/L)･Ton

∆iL‘=((Vin-Vout)/L)･Toff

Vout=Vin/(1-D)

Can I calculate current changes(∆iL - ∆iL‘) during dynamic state by using the same equations?

PWM period is around 20us and simulator has more than 40us step time. So I have no option but to calculate iL, Vout by PWM duty.

[image]

Comment: There's something wrong with your sim or models if you can't get at least one AC cycle worth of data with a 10 ns maximum step size. It might take 2 minutes but, worth the wait. If you want a theoretical value then consider the boundary case of CCM and not the general case. If you aren't using boundary CCM then you need to provide much more detail.

Comment: Can you please mention where does the figure come from, it is important to reference sources. Then, what are you trying to determine here? The small-signal response of a PFC stage?

Comment: `... during dynamic state` what do you mean by dynamic state? The voltage-current relation of an inductor always applies. The formulas and the waveforms in your question appear to belong to a DC-DC boost converter but note that for a boost PFC the voltage across the inductor changes over the time because the input is a rectified sine. So you can still use the V = L di/dt but V depends on the angle of the input sine.

Comment: @VerbalKint
Here is the reference source
https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/application_note_en_20191106_AKX00080.pdf?did=68570

Comment: I see, they use the on- and off-slopes to determine the dc transfer characteristic of the CCM boost converter. Yes, these equations are always valid so you can use them for other applications, if \$V_{in}\$ changes for instance and you want to predict the new peak current. Nothing special here I believe.

Comment: @RohatKılıç
AC source is rectified 50~60Hz sine, and T = 20us, Figure 4.2 is just a 1 period of PWM cycle.

Comment: @VerbalKint Thank you. Regarding small-signal response, I think I don't fully understand   small-signal response, could you recommend some papers about this? I mean "small-signal response of a PFC stage". It would be very appreciated.

Comment: Small-signal modeling is a vast territory and you can have a look at my free [seminars](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Divers/Christophe%20Basso%20Tech%20Seminar%20Proposals.pdf) n° 5 and 6 for a start and if you want to see the technique applied to PFCs, my [book](https://stairwaypress.com/product/transfer-functions-of-switching-converters/) on transfer functions of switching functions covers the subject.